# How use JOIN LEFT in Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models tables, like

```
Project = Sequelize.define('Project',{
  name: Sequelize.STRING
});

Task = Sequelize.define('Task',{
  name:Sequelize.STRING,
  status: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
  deadline: Sequelize.DATE,
  from_name: Sequelize.STRING,
  ProjectId: Sequelize.INTEGER
});
```

I need to find all records from two tables. How do I perform this query in Sequelize?

```
SELECT * FROM mydb.Projects 
LEFT JOIN  mydb.Tasks ON Projects.id = Tasks.Project_id
```

I using:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {

  Project.hasMany(Task,{ foreignKey: { allowNull: false }, onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
  Project.all({
    include: [{
      model: Task,
      required:false,
      where:{ProjectId: Sequelize.col('Project.id')}
    }]
  })
  .then(function (projects) {
    res.render('TODOList', {title: 'TODO',  projects: projects || [] });
    console.log(projects);
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      res.render('TODOList', {title: 'TODO List'});
    }
  });

};
```

but I get records only from Project, like:

```
Project {
  dataValues: { 
    id: 5,
    name: 'pr2',
    createdAt: 2017-08-20T07:03:09.000Z,
    updatedAt: 2017-08-20T07:41:47.000Z,
    Tasks: [Object] 
  }
}
```

How I can get records Task (Project.dataValues.Task)?

Comment: that's called: `eager loading` and actually it's best way of doing it with ORM, wait a little I'll give You solution in answer

Comment: What does "all records from two tables" mean? Left join returns inner join rows plus unmatched left table row extended by nulls. Inner join returns all combinations of a left table row & a right table row that also meet the on condition. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy, This means that I need to get projects and all the records that relate to them.

Comment: That is still unclear. Please edit your question, comments are not for clarifications. Use enough words to clearly say what you mean. You want rows with what columns, when the columns have what values, in terms of the base tables? Do you actually want the result of the left join you give? Your descriptions are nothing like what a left join returns. Please act on all of my last comment also.

Comment: @ВоваЖуравлёв You want usual array of objects, You may map array and call `toJSON()` (as in my answer)

Answer (score 0):

So models are (say it: `db/models.js`):

```
const
  Project = Sequelize.define(
    'Project',
    {
      name: Sequelize.STRING
    }),
  Task = Sequelize.define(
    'Task', 
    {
      name: Sequelize.STRING,
      status: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      deadline: Sequelize.DATE,
      from_name: Sequelize.STRING,
      ProjectId: Sequelize.INTEGER
    });   

// relations must be defined once in model definition part (not like You do in every request
Project.hasMany(Task, {foreignKey: {allowNull: false}, onDelete: 'CASCADE'});
Task.belongsTo(Project);

module.exports = {Project, Task};
```

And in Your router's handler (say it `routes/projects/list.js`):

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const {Project, Task} = require('../../db/models');

module.exports.list = (req, res) => {
  const query = {
    include: [{
      model: Task,
      as: 'tasks',
      required: false
    }]
  };
  Project
    .all(query)
    .then(function (projects) {
      // it's not recommended, but You insist to get read of model instances and have normal array of objects
      projects = projects ? projects.map(project => project.toJSON()) : [];

      res.render(
        'TODOList', 
        {
          title: 'TODO',  
          projects
        });
        console.log(projects);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.render('TODOList', {title: 'TODO List'});
    });
};
```

but since sequelize returns array of sequelize model instances - it's normal to have `dataValues` don't worry just use as usual:

```
for(let project of projects) {
  console.log(project.tasks[0].name);
}
```

Comment: Thank very much, it's working for me! I realized my mistake

Comment: @ВоваЖуравлёв happy that was helpful